# Will Framerate effect particle emitter during render?

Tags: rendering, particles

i made a snow particle on my scene, and i've set up everything to appear on the right time. in solid view, its moving exactly the way i want, but unfortunately when i switch to render preview mode, it appears to have a bit of a drag, moving really slow, with a bit of a lag. sometimes not appearing in the scene at all. will this effect my final render? what if i use sheepit to render, will it be effect too?

Comment: No, the render preview is live rendering each frame as fast as it can, which in a really heavy scene will cause lag. When you render, Blender will take as long as it needs (given your render setting) to render each image comprising one frame Then, on conversion to a video format, it will playback will play those rendered images in order at the selected framerate.

Comment: so the particle wont go haywire all of the sudden when i render it, like its having a rave then? what do you mean by render setting? i mean which setting should i adjust or maybe keep an eye on?

Answer (score 1):

As Jakemoyo said, the render preview is not a real-time preview of what your final rendered video will look like. Eevee comes close but in practice it still takes a good few seconds to render each frame of a decent scene.

If you're previewing the render and hitting play, you will not see an accurate representation of the end frame rate (which is set here in the Output Properties tab:)

[image]

You will instead see the best frame rate your machine can put out, and each frame will not have finished render quality.

Only when you fully render your scene and view the finished result will you see... the finished result!

In practice, many animators render their animations out in reduced resolution and/or quality first in order to get a quick result that resembles what the final article will look like without committing to a long render, but I digress.